# Find first visible worksheet using RubyXL

Tags: ruby, rubyxl

I am parsing an Excel workbook using RubyXL and discovered that `workbook[0]` returns the first worksheet regardless of whether it is hidden.

I would like to isolate the first **visible** worksheet by coding something like `workbook[0].not_hidden`.

How can this be done in RubyXL?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out visibility is held in a parameter called @state, where a visible worksheet has `@state = nil` and a hidden worksheet has `@state = 'hidden'`.

So, to isolate the first visible worksheet:

```
worksheet = workbook.select{ |w| w.state.blank? }[0]
```

Or, to isolate the first hidden worksheet:

```
worksheet = workbook.select{ |w| w.state == 'hidden' }[0]
```